# PC's are able to bypass WNDR4500v2 DNS settings

Tags: router, dns

I have a WNDR4500v2 Netgear router with OpenDNS as my DNS in the router. I have an account on OpenDNS with some custom filtering to help keep some of the worst of the web at bay.
All the mobile devices (androids and kindle's) that connect get DNS filtering as expected but I've noticed my Linux machines (and the one Windows desktop) do not. They override the router's DNS setting.
Is there a way to prevent this other than setting the DNS in each machine?
If I did it that way then I would have to change the settings even in guest devices that come over (laptops would be the main issue).

Comment: This is to be expected because each client device can do exactly that.

Comment: So the only way to prevent this would be to set up a server with all traffic routing through it?

Comment: Even if you did that.  They could still change their DNS server.